# How to change button text on page load based on listview value on Visual Studio

Tags: c#, asp.net

I want to change my button text on page load after retrieving the list view values.

For example,

```
<asp:Label ID="favouriteLabel" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("favourite") %>' />
```

If this label value is 1, the button will change to Favourited.

I have retrieved the list view values by binding the listview

```
protected void ListView1_ItemDataBound(object sender, ListViewItemEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Item.ItemType == ListViewItemType.DataItem)
        {
            Label activity = (Label)e.Item.FindControl("favouriteLabel");
            activityID =  activity.Text;               
        }
    }
```

then, I get the activityID and do a simple if-else check on the page load

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {         
        if (activityID == "1")
        {
            Button4.Text = "Favourited";
        }
        else
        {
            Button4.Text = "Favourite";
        }

    }
```

However it does not work. Anybody?

Comment: have you tried debugging your code?what is the value of activityID?it must be null i think.

Answer (score 0):

Do that inside a PostBack check in the load event, for instance:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                if (activityID == "1")
                {
                    Button4.Text = "Favourited";
                }
                else
                {
                    Button4.Text = "Favourite";
                }
            }
        }
```

Read more about postback [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5zabsw0t%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Answer (score 0):

Page_Load happens before your ItemDataBound event so the activityId you are looking at in the Page_Load will never be 1.

Just put the code you have in the Page_Load into the ItemDataBoundEvent